# Export/Create XML File from SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype

I need to create an XML file from my database (Oracle) and save it to a specific location.

So far I have tried different variants, where I either only saw the XML elements in the command line or got any error messages continuously.

The XML file should have the following columns:
1. order_id that counts up 
2. date
3. recording location, from another table, which is considered PK and FK, which order_id of the first table.

At first I was guided by this example:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/generating-xml-from-sql-and-plsql-part-2/

//First Try

```
DECLARE
   l_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN l_refcursor FOR SELECT a.ORDER_ID
                             , a.DATE,
                             b.CITY
                          FROM TABLE1 a
                          LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
                            ON a.ORDER_ID = b.ORDER_ID
                            WHERE a.ORDER_ID <= 5;
   l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(l_refcursor);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
END;
/
```

//Second Try:

```
SELECT XMLElement("Order_ID"
                 , ORDER_ID
                 )
     , XMLElement("DATE",
                 DATE
                 )
  FROM Table1
  WHERE AUFTRAGS_ID <= 5;
```

First Try:
Result
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Problem: I cant find any XML File for this on the server. So something is missing here.

Second Try:

### Result

1
2018-01-31
...

Problem: No XML File

Comment: you create an XML object but you do not create a file with XML in your procedure. so why do you expect a file?

Comment: You can use either `UTL_FILE` or `SPOOL`